# Unable to identify the correct timezone of the Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to get the timezone of my Oracle 11g database. I run the following query:

```
select dbtimezone from dual;
```

DBTIMEZONE 
-------------------
+00:00

Then I tried the following query and checked the properties of the database to see the timezone:

```
select property_name, property_value from database_properties;
```

Property_Name  |  PROPERTY_VALUE  
---------------------------------------------------
DBTIMEZONE .... 00:00

Now I want to change the timezone of my database. For that I run the following query:

```
alter database set time_zone='-06:00';
```

database set TIME_ZONE='-06:00' altered.

Now, when i am trying to get the timezone by the query:

```
select dbtimezone from dual;
```

DBTIMEZONE
-------------
+00:00

It didn't reflected the changes here.

But when I checked the timezone in the properties of the database, I got the changed one:

```
select property_name, property_value, description from database_properties;
```

Property_Name  |  Property_Value  
---------------------------------------------
DBTIMEZONE .....-06:00

Then why the Dual table is not showing the altered timezone?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_1006.htm#SQLRF00802) (search for `set_time_zone_clause`): the `set time_zone` modification only takes effect after you restart the database.

> After setting or changing the time zone with this clause, you must restart the database for the new time zone to take effect.

Demo:

```
SQL> select dbtimezone from dual;

DBTIME
------
+00:00

SQL> alter database set time_zone = '+01:00' ;

Database altered.

SQL> select dbtimezone from dual;

DBTIME
------
+00:00

SQL> shutdown immediate;
Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1610612736 bytes
Fixed Size                  2924928 bytes
Variable Size             754978432 bytes
Database Buffers          838860800 bytes
Redo Buffers               13848576 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
SQL> select dbtimezone from dual;

DBTIME
------
+01:00
```

Comment: But the changes cannot be seen when the query 'select dbtimezone from dual' is used. It displays 00:00 always

Comment: It doesn't if you restart.